# htaccess redirect rule without affacting existing directory

Tags: .htaccess

I need a .htaccess rule that redircts: http://www.mysite.com/{username}/{id}

to : http://www.mysite.com/video.php?username={username}&id={id}

The difficulty is that it should not affect the existing directories such as images/ script/ admin/ js/ music/ etc...

(http://www.mysite.com/images/logo.jpeg  should not be affeted by this rule)

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try, to use this code into the `.htaccess` file of your site:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /video.php?username=%1&id=%2 [R]
```

---

Now, if you want to rewrite and not to redirect? Simply, just remove the `[R]` flag:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /video.php?username=%1&id=%2
```

Comment: that's GOOD...
Except that browser shows now: www.monsite.com/video.php?username=ana&id=1

Is there a way to show www.monsite.com/ana/1 ?

Comment: What? Do you mean, to rewrite and not to redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /video.php?username=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```